# An example of an uncountable collection of disjoint open intervals? Possible?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

I sense that it is not possible.
But, I have been unable to demonstrate precisely why it is not possible.

I have tried something along the lines of:

Consider two real numbers, $r_1, r_2$ such that $r_1 < r_2.$ The real number $r_1$ corresponds to an open interval $i_1$ whose lower bound is strictly less than that of $i_2,$ which corresponds to $r_2.$ I then tried to show that there are infinitely many real numbers between $r_1$ and $r_2,$ but not infinitely many open intervals between $i_1$ and $i_2.$ But, it seems that there are.

Is this about the right way to approach the probably, that is, to understand the real numbers to be in bijection with the uncountable set of open and disjoint intervals, and then show a contradiction?

Guidance will be appreciated. A given answer will purloin the possibility that I may come upon the insight myself, which, the realization of that possibility being a joyful experience, will leave me a bit grave!

Comment: There is a rational in each such open intervals which is not in the others.

Comment: For what it's worth, this IS possible in the [long line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_(topology)) (see [here](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/math431/LongLine.pdf) also) . . .

Comment: also, the unit square with lex order has continuum many disjoint open intervals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your attempt was implicitly assuming two things:

- "Uncountable" means "In bijection with $\mathbb{R}$."
- The putative bijection needed to be "order-preserving" in the sense that if $r_1<r_2$ then the infimum of the interval associated to $r_1$ is less than the infimum of the interval associated to $r_2$.

Both of these are unjustified. In particular, the first one in this context is essentially the [continuum hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis), which is known to be neither provable nor disprovable from [the usual axioms of set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory)!

---

Instead, you're going to need to think a bit more geometrically. The idea, essentially, is that there isn't enough "room" to fit uncountably many open intervals into $\mathbb{R}$ without some overlap. I think a good hint at this point is to observe that open intervals are "filled in" in a sense: any *dense* subset of $\mathbb{R}$ intersects every (nonempty) open interval. So:

> Can you think of a dense set of reals which is "small" in some sense having to do with cardinality?

The point is that disjoint open sets overlap a dense set in different ways (they can't overlap at the same point), so if we have a "small" dense set we have in some sense a limit to how many disjoint open intervals we can get.

This should get you started (and hopefully doesn't give away the answer); leave a comment if you want me to provide further hints.

Comment: Thank you, Noah! I'll think it over and get back to you if I have any questions! :)

Comment: Hi, Noah. May you consider this proof by contradiction. The real numbers are dense, signifying that an infinite quantity of rational numbers is contained between any two real numbers.

Comment: Consider any two disjoint open intervals. By the density of the real numbers, it can be said definitely that a rational number is contained between the supremum of the lesser interval and the infimum of the greater interval (lesser and greater corresponding to the respective infimums of the intervals). Therefore, as there are uncountably many disjoint open intervals, the set of rational numbers contained between every two disjoint and open intervals is uncountable. However, the set of rational numbers is a countable set, and any subset of the rational numbers is countable.

Comment: That set of rational numbers contained between the disjoint and open intervals is a subset of all rational numbers, which contradicts the conclusion that it must be an uncountable set of rational numbers.

Comment: Thank you for your consideration!

Comment: @RafaelVergnaud " Therefore, as there are uncountably many disjoint open intervals, the set of rational numbers contained between every two disjoint and open intervals is uncountable." Not quite - e.g. there are no rationals between $(1, \pi)$ and $(\pi, 4)$. Instead, think about rationals *inside* the intervals. We can assign to each interval a rational inside it. If the intervals are disjoint, what can we say about such a map? And what does that have to do with the cardinality of the set of intervals in question?

Comment: I see! Yes. I should have been more careful. It is essentially the same argument, choosing some rational $r$ contained in the open interval $I$ to correspond to $I$ in the mapping. Therefore, if the set of open and disjoint intervals is uncountable, so is the set of rational numbers that map injectively onto that set of open and disjoint intervals, which contradictions that the rational numbers, and any subset thereof, is countable. I hope I haven't made yet another error, and this will finish your work here! Thank you Noah :)